# Text field and images are nil

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, viewcontroller

When the app runs it crashed and write the text field is nil and the images are nil and write you must warp its and didn't open the view controller which has this images and text field

```
Name = (UITextField!) nil

phone = (UITextField!) nil

url = (UITextField!) nil

Name = (UIImageView!) nil
```

Comment: Please write your question in a way by which user can understand your requirement

Comment: the app didn't open the view controller which have this things

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You assign `nil` to variables that shouldn't be nil, of course it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created the UITextField and UIImageViews objects using nib or in storyboard, check whether the IBOutlets of them are connected.

If you have created these UI elements via code(in a function), check the function is getting called.

Comment: When I go to this view controller I user                                                      let a = name_The_ViewController()                                                                  present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)